# error in program while connecting my android application to the mysqlite server

Tags: php, android, mysqli, phpmyadmin

**Error:**

> **Fatal error**: Call to a member function query() on a non object in
>   **....Rrgister.php** on line **9**

my Register.php file is

```
  <?php
require "conn.php";
$name=$_POST["name"];
$surname=$_POST["surname"];
$age=$_POST["age"];
$user_name=$_POST["user_name"];
$user_pass=$_POST["password"];
$mysql_qry="insert into candidates(name,surname,age,user_name,user_pass) values('$name','$surname','$age','$user_name','$user_pass')";
if($conn->query($mysql_qry)=== TRUE){
    echo "Insert Successfull";
}
else
{
    echo "Error".$mysql_qry."<br>".$conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

my conn.php

```
<?php
    $db_name="candidates"; 
    $mysql_username="user"; 
    $mysql_password="password"; 
    $server_name="........."; 
    $conn = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_username, $mysql_password,$db_name);
?>
```

Comment: please, share you "conn.php" script

Comment: <?php
$db_name="candidates";
$mysql_username="user";
$mysql_password="password";
$server_name=".........";

$conn = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_username, $mysql_password,$db_name);

?>

Comment: Add that to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: i think `mysqli_connect()` fails, that's why $conn is not an object, try to add `or die("error connecting...");` to `mysqli_connect()` and open that link from regular browser

Answer (score 0):

If you use structural connect you should use:

1.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "Your query");
```

If you use object connect then:

2.

```
$conn->query("Your query");
```

It seems you connect by procedural so try first example and read - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: sorry i m not clear with this.Please elaborate as i m new to android and develop my 1st app. So please elaborate

Comment: after adding these codes now i get Errorinsert into Candidates

Comment: As you can see you have a connection to the database you have an error when creating a query from a debug code var_dump () step by step and see where the code crashes you can paste me how variable var_dump ($mysql_qry);

Comment: where i have to setup this query?